# Reasons for using get parameter for detecting ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Are there any reasons for detecting ajax requests using an appended GET parameter (like 'ajax=1') instead of just checking the 'X-Requested-With' header on the server side?

It probably makes sense if we're unsure of whether the JS framework used by the client propagates the header, but are there any advantages if we know we do? Are there any situations this could come in handy?

Comment: AJAX requests are not limited to just the GET method. How would you implement this for POST, PUT, DELETE etc? Why is the server side code reliant on the `X-Requested-With` header being present in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Practically there is no difference between a AJAX request or a typical page refresh sent by a browser to the server.

if you want you can try a tool like Fiddler, then you will realize both requests are alike.

If you really want to detect if a request is made as an AJAX request, only reliable way is to explicitly add some value to the request. It can be added to the url as you say `ajax=1` or in a custom HTTP Header, or in the request body in case of a POST request.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I mean is the header approach seems so much better (different types of requests are handled identically, no additional variables mess with actual POST and GET data, url-reliant code won't break), that I've started wondering if it has some hidden drawbacks, as there are people using parameter approach out there (e.g. Rails, as far as I know).